# C++ Library free pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11

I am creating a simple C++ MIDI library and I ran into a small problem. Currently, I have implemented everything but the reading of files. Internally, I have a `std::vector` with raw, dynamically allocated pointers (with the `new()` keyword) of events, which is an abstract class and can therefore not be instantiated. Now that I've finally started on the reading part, there is a slight problem. I will have to allocate the objects myself and later free them too. This creates problems though, since the user of the library may include events in between or append them. This will mean that there are dynamic pointers that have been created elsewhere in my `std::vector`, which makes freeing a difficult question.

To make this question more general, I was wondering what I should do with pointers provided by the user of the library. What should I do with them? I was thinking one of the points on the list:

1. Free all pointers and note that pointers given to the class do not have to be freed any more (which seems strange and counter-intuitive, since the new is matched with the delete in a completely different setting)
2. Maintain a list of pointers provided by the user and simply skip any pointer in that list (probably not really a solution, because the entire list would have to be checked every time)
3. Making the creation of events only available with the class, so the user cannot create pointers with the new keyword but only by letting the handling class allocate them.
4. Forcing the use of shared pointers and using them exclusively in my code, so that they will be automatically freed when they go out of scope.
5. Maintaining a list of your own pointers and only freeing them, and let the user given pointers go out of scope / they will have to clean them up themselves.
6. ...? (something I have maybe not thought of?)

So please, tell me what is customary in a situation like this, where the user of the library provides pointers which is added to a list maintained by you and then the list goes out of scope, while you have your own pointers mixed with theirs.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: One or more code samples would help to improve this question a lot.

Comment: Why do they have to be dynamically allocated? Why can't you use smart pointers?

Comment: Why do you want pointers? Just have a vector of events?

Comment: The point is, Event is an abstract class since there should not be an instantiation of an event with nothing, it can only be a Message, SysEx or Meta event. However, since they all stem from event and event has some basic functionality, I needed it as an abstract class. This means, since std::vector uses this class, it needs to be able to be instantiated, since it will be copied. This is impossible however, and will also cause slicing.

Comment: Think about using [boost::variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/variant/) instead of inheritance. MIDI events/messages should have value semantics. Remember: [If all you have is a hammer, everything looks like a nail](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/if_all_you_have_is_a_hammer,_everything_looks_like_a_nail)

Comment: @nosid I have to disagree, I think the identity does matter. For example, we cannot say a lot about a message in general, except that it has a delta time. Apart from that, every message has its own statuses, bytes, orderings and general syntax. Correct me if I'm wrong though, I'm not completely familiar on the subject of value semantics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pick a consistent policy. Don't choose any of those options that lead to you have to destroy some objects in some places and other objects in other places. Especially not those approaches in which the user is responsible for destroying some objects but not others. Ownership should be handled uniformly.

My first suggestion would be to avoid dynamically allocating objects completely. Can you not store a `std::vector<Event>` and pass `Event`s by value to and from your library? Then the user can happily not care about the ownership of objects, but they can choose to dynamically allocate them if they wish.

If you really need to dynamically allocate objects, I suggest that you always wrap them in smart pointers so that ownership is managed automatically. If, for example, you are allocating some object on behalf of the user, the standard interface for this is something like:

```
std::unique_ptr<Object> createObject();
```

If, on the other hand, your library has some internal dynamically allocated that it needs to share with the user, return a `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: Unfortunately, Event is abstract and cannot be instantiated, which requires me to handle them as pointers, because it could virtually be anything which has event as its base.

Comment: So, should I force users of the library to give me only smart pointers? Is that good style? Because to me that just feels strange. An as for the consistent policy, I would completely agree but that would mean me freeing user-provided pointers, which also feels strange. Is there maybe another way to uniformally treat an abstract class, maybe not using pointers?

Comment: References also work polymorphically, but probably wouldn't be very useful in this case because you're dealing with objects with dynamic lifetimes. So you're saying the user will create `Event`s and pass them to your library? In this case, it depends on what you want to say to the user. Are you saying "Pass me your `Event` and I will share it with you", or are you saying "Pass me your `Event` and I'll manage it"? In the first case, take a `shared_ptr`. In the second case, I suggest the ideal interface is just to take a const reference and then have the library copy it.

Comment: The second case is exactly what I am looking for and the perfect answer to my question, I never thought of solving it like that. :) This will also mean that the user does not have to create all the events and keep track of them to delete them later, but rather creating one event, setting its parameters and simply pass them along. There should be no need to make the user keep track of the Events, since they could be obtained anyway if it was really needed. This solves everything!